# Is there any tool for coordinate system detection from a point coordinate?

Tags: coordinate-system, tools

I have bounding box points below;

> -20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34

Let's think about a tool that gives one of these points as an input and returns the coordinate system/projection which is appropriate. Is there any tool to do this job?

> "-20037508.34" --> Tool -> ED50

By the way what is the projection of coordinates showed above?

Comment: You have to make a number of assumptions to determine projection from coordinate values alone. There are hundreds of standard coordinate systems for which any coordinate values could be appropriate, and an infinite number of  custom coordinate systems.

Comment: Ok, but some values are indicate only one projection, right?

Comment: Only if you know the exact location and datum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if this is a french site, I think it may be interessant : 

https://projection.dogeo.fr/coords-to-points

This site makes it possible to obtain the coordinates of a point or to locate a point when we have its coordinates.

It also makes it possible to compare the coordinates of a point according to the different possible projections.

Comment: Be careful with this, you might get a close projection but it could still be incorrect, especially if using the wrong datum.