# Getting Projection Code (EPSG) from Coordinates and known location

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

I have Coordinates (x=3381438.573, y=5794542.432) and a location (somewhere south of Berlin). Is there a way to find out the Projection code this data was defined with? A website would be nice.

Comment: https://epsg.io/ is one possibility. The coordinates look a lot like DHDN Zone 3 - but then the points wouldn't be south of Berlin.

Comment: Still, I dont know how to find a specific projection to my coordinates, besides manually trying every possible projection.

Comment: It's easier to identify the projCRS or possible projCRS but much more difficult to narrow it down to a particular geoCRS if there are multiple ones for the area. Possible duplicate: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261601/is-there-any-tool-for-coordinate-system-detection-from-a-point-coordinate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search with [ProjFinder](http://projfinder.com/) reveals that your coordinate reference system might be one of these :

- [EPSG:3835](https://epsg.io/3835) Name:Pulkovo 1942(83) / Gauss-Kruger zone 3
- [EPSG:3333](https://epsg.io/3333) Name:Pulkovo 1942(58) / Gauss-Kruger zone 3

Which correspond to a point located just south of Ludwigsfelde, near [52°15'58.7"N, 13°15'41.3"E](https://www.google.com/maps/place/52%C2%B015'58.7%22N+13%C2%B015'41.3%22E/@52.265992,13.2518852,14.5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d52.2663056!4d13.2614722):

[image]

Without more information, it is hard to tell which datum version it corresponds to, since both appear to differ by only a few meters.